# Why sometimes need to wait a minute to accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, new-users, spam

Sorry if I'm asking a stupid question here. This is my first post on `meta stackoverflow`. I using SO quite a long time and I like it not because  most of my questions can get answered, but I also find that I learn most from answering questions. But why sometimes I need to wait for some minutes to accept an answer? I understand that we allow to post a question after 90 minutes to avoid spam, but will accept an answer will consider as a spam also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions with an accepted answer tend to get less attention than those without (unsurprisingly), and the first answer that comes isn't necessarily the best answer you're going to get. The delay before you can accept is to attract more answers, and to encourage you to accept the best one in terms of things like the depth and relevance of explanation in it, and the general approach it uses to solve your problem.

Comment: if so , why this message is shown few and far between? why not always?

Comment: @partho I believe the timeout does apply every single time. You might just not be running into it very often. Keep in mind it counts from the time the *question* is posted - as far as I understand, you can theoretically accept an answer that is only seconds old provided you asked the question atleast 15 minutes ago.